# Que pode ser classificada em preposição?

Tags: gramática, classe-gramatical

Na língua inglesa, embora prescritivistas tradicionalmente a classifiquem exclusivamente em conjunção, a palavra *[than](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Than)* pode ser também classificada em preposição. Sob tal ponto de vista, frases como "*She is taller than me*" não são consideradas solecismos. Como estava interessado na situação análoga na língua portuguesa, fiz uma pequena pesquisa na internet, mas não fui capaz de encontrar nenhuma referência à classificação da palavra *que*, quando usada no sentido comparativo acima descrito, em preposição por gramáticos ou linguistas. Como falante nativo de português brasileiro, nenhuma das frases “*mais alto que mim*” e “*mais alto que eu*” me parece completamente natural, mas da pesquisa concluo que apenas esta está adequada à norma padrão. Isto posto, minha pergunta é a seguinte: existem argumentos linguísticos a favor da classificação da palavra *que* em preposição no português? Aparentemente, Camões utilizou-a dessa maneira na expressão "*maior que mim*" em um de seus [poemas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-significado-da-expressao-dar-porrada-de-cego/17157), mas não me parece que esse uso imediatamente legalizaria usos similares na norma padrão do português contemporâneo.

Comment: A frase «Ela é mais alta que eu» é comum em português de Portugal.

Comment: Acredito que ela também seja a mais comum no Brasil. Todavia, não me soa completamente natural sem o verbo explicitamente escrito (quiçá por interferência do inglês).

Comment: PS: Por verbo explicitamente escrito, quis dizer "Ela é mais alta do que eu sou".

Comment: Não acho Camões exemplo de bom português — bom = boa prática — para hoje, até porque o português de Camões é o português moderno; o português de hoje é português contemporâneo. "(Do) que"" é conjunção comparativa (Infopédia); lembrando que uma palavra pode ter várias classificações gramaticais, que é o caso de "que". Para mim, "ele é mais que ela" é bem natural e uso normalmente, mas "ele é mais legal que mim" soa errado e é considerado errado pelos gramáticos. Porém (próximo comentário meu):

Comment: @Schilive Obrigado por me esclarecer a diferença entre português contemporâneo e português moderno. Corrigi o texto da pergunta.

Comment: “Que” pode ser classificado como preposição, mas é controverso. Encontrei no Dicionário Houssaiss dois significados para “que” como preposição. O primeiro, que não vira no Priberam, é com o significado "senão", "salvo", "exceto", como em "não tem outros afazeres que os domésticos"; eu nunca pensei neste uso como preposição :). O segundo, que é o realmente converso, é sobre o amado verbo “ter”, já que é comum dizer "tenho que" no lugar de "tenho de"; alguns gramáticos apontam o fato de "ter que" estar errado, pois "que" deveria se preposição; ou seja, há gramáticos que põem-na como preposição.

Comment: De fato, há pouco estava lendo algumas respostas no _Cibedúvidas da Língua Portuguesa_, e descobri que a palavra _salvo_ tem classificação instável: classificação em classe de palavras não é uma ciência exata.

Comment: @BourbakiWannabe, não é errado pegar exemplo de Camões, só se tem que ter cuidado porque é de 1550 e é considerado pela maioria dos gramáticos como uma outra fase do português, mas ainda é português. Uma língua geralmente não muda como um estalo de dedos, é demorado para diabo e é geralmente suave — ao poucos. Por isso que, se leres Camões, não vais falar "isto não é português, nem por 1 milhão de réis"; não há problema em pegar exemplo de Camões, é só lembrar que é de 1550 — "poucado" velho.

Comment: "Mais alta do que eu" soa perfeitamente natural a mim. A omissão do 'de' é desaconselhada e estranha.